# tier_prices.phtml with custom script not render on product detail page - Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2

I have made a wholesale tier price table for the B2B group customers according to [this (tier price table)](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/See-tier-price-in-a-table/td-p/59598), but I cannot make the new script in tier_prices.phtml render on the product page. Instead, it still renders the phtml file from vendor / magento module directory.

Here is the path: `<theme_dir>`/`<Magento_Catalog>`/`<templates>`/`<product>`/`<price>`/`tier_prices.phtml`

I am not sure how to move the templates file under base to child theme. Do I need anything else than just moving the phtml to templates?

Comment: Hi @sharon, you are doing it right. make sure you are doing this in current/child theme.

Comment: Hi @Ramkishan, I tested to override other template files in web on the same theme, and it works, but not this particular tier_prices.phtml file. I used the developer tool to check the file path and block on product page, and it is still rendering the default file. I also did the setup:upgrade and clean cache multiple. Nothing happen. Very frustrated now.

Comment: Your file path is correct. Let me try this with my theme at local.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally found out in Magento 2.2.6 there is another default module for configurable product specifically:

module-configurable-product

in vendor/magento directory. So basically copy

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml

to

> theme_dir/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/tier_price.phtml